# "error: source file is not valid UTF-8" when linking on Mac in CMake project

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker, ninja

I have a cross platform CMake project which uses a few third party dependencies. On Windows this builds fine, however when building on Mac using ninja I get the following error when linking [Optick](https://github.com/bombomby/optick):

```
[949/972] Linking CXX shared library Engine/External/optick/libOptickCore.dylib
FAILED: Engine/External/optick/libOptickCore.dylib 
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -x objective-c++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o Engine/External/optick/libOptickCore.dylib -install_name @rpath/libOptickCore.dylib Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_capi.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_core.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_gpu.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_gpu.d3d12.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_gpu.vulkan.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_message.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_miniz.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_serialization.cpp.o Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_server.cpp.o   && :
Engine/External/optick/CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/optick_capi.cpp.o:1:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+000C><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0004><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0008><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000> <U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0019><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><88><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H
^
```

These errors seem to happen on all object files generated from the OptickCore target.

The project is generated via CMake and it configures fine.

```
The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

Optick in the CMake script is linked via `target_link_libraries` where I link `OptickCore` as `PUBLIC` and then add the Optick `CMakeLists.txt` as a subdirectory.

The charset of the source files are all us-ascii

```
matthewloveday@192 src % file -I optick_capi.cpp
optick_capi.cpp: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
```

And the charset of the object file is binary

```
matthewloveday@192 src % file -I optick_capi.cpp.o     
optick_capi.cpp.o: application/x-mach-binary; charset=binary
```

I've never dealt with this error before so I'm not sure where to start, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error occurs during the **link**, so option `-x objective-c++` in that command line is wrong.  It is not CMake who adds this option, and it is not Optic project either. Probably, the option is added by **your project**, so without your **code** we cannot help you. Note, that don't need all your "production" code, but expect the code in form of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the not shown CMakeLists.txt.

You're telling AppleClang that all of its inputs are Objective-C++ file sources: `-x objective-c++`, whereas you are given the object files `optick_capi.cpp.o optick_core.cpp.o ...`. AppleClang correctly is telling you that `optick_capi.cpp.o` is not a UTF-8 encoded Objective-C++ source file.

Comment: Ok, those build commands are generated via CMake though. I'm just going Configure > Generate > Ninja Build. Do you have any idea where the issue may lie within a CMake configuration that could cause this?

Comment: If you use the master branch of optick, you know, it's for the active development. I suggest that you use the sources tagged with the latest release 1.4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're somehow building Optik so that it builds its object files into its own source directory. As it has a [really bad glob](https://github.com/bombomby/optick/blob/8abd28dee1a4034c973a3d32cd1777118e72df7e/CMakeLists.txt#L21) for source files it'll pick up any object files as sources too.

You should change the glob to only pick up cpp and header files or even better don't use a glob at all [as recommended by cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem)

Comment: "As it has a really bad glob for source files it'll pick up any object files as sources too." - The directory `..../CMakeFiles/OptickCore.dir/src/` is clearly under the **build tree**, and `file(GLOB OPTICK_SRC "src/*.*")` doesn't grub files from there. Also, the erroneous step is the **linkage**, so it definitely does not use files added as **source** ones (via `add_library`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, but it is clearly picking up files from there, my guess would be that `FetchContent` or similar is being used and that is doing an in source build

Comment: " but it is clearly picking up files from there" - For the **linkage** step CMake picks generated(*compiled*) **object** files. There is no problems in that: CMake always separates *compiling* and *linking* into different steps. The problem is that *compiler* option `-x objective-c++` is added for the *linkage* step...